# Sumar las veces que aparece un valor en una columna y agregando el resultado en otra con pandas python3

Tags: python, excel, pandas

En un programa que estoy realizando con python tomo un documento excel y lo filtro, después lo acomodo de menor a mayor respecto a la columna No_Ptas, lo que no logro hacer es poder sumar esa columna pero solo los valores iguales.

Ejemplo:

```
No_Ptas Total
0.5       3
0.5       3
0.5       3
2.0       5
2.0       5
2.0       5
2.0       5
2.0       5
3.0       1
```

En el ejemplo se ve que 0.5 se repite 3 veces y se agrega el 3 en total, no importa que se siga repitiendo el 3 hacía abajo, eso se puede quitar con **duplicates()**.

Código:

```
#Importamos las bibliotecas pandas , tinys3
import pandas as pd
import tinys3

def main ():

    # Declaramos una variable para poder darle la lectura del archivo
    xls = pd.read_excel('Enfriadores.xlsx','Hoja1',usecols=['UO','Estatus_Equipo','Estatus_Eq_Disponible','No_Ptas'])

    # Declaramos otra variable para poder hacer el filtro
    filtro = xls[ ( xls.UO.isin(['TLALNEPANTLA']) ) & ( xls.Estatus_Equipo.isin(['DISPONIBLE']) ) & ( xls.Estatus_Eq_Disponible.isin(['NUEVO']) ) ]  

    #Muestra la información que contiene la variable filtro
    print ( filtro.sort_values('No_Ptas') ) #Menor a mayor

main()
```

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` y aplicar el método `count` a la columna. Esto genera una Serie que puedes convertir de nuevo a DataFrame mediante el método `pandas.Series.to_frame`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"No_Ptas": [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0]})
res = df.groupby("No_Ptas")["No_Ptas"].count().to_frame("Total").reset_index()
```

o usar el método `describe`:

```
res = df.groupby("No_Ptas")["No_Ptas"].describe()[['count']].reset_index()
res.rename(columns={"count": "Total"}, inplace=True)
```

> ```
>    No_Ptas  Foo
> 0      0.5    3
> 1      2.0    5
> 2      3.0    1
> ```

Comment: Muchas gracias, he solucionado mi problema (: